# How do I get all DbContext classes and all DbSet under each DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am working on a large project with 50+ `DbContext` and 100+ `DbSet` under each `DbContext`.

Each `DbContext` is handling by a separate team, and they are adding/removing `DbSet`'s as per their requirement/changes.

From a centralized view / report, I would like to see all `DbContext` classes and all `DbSet` under each `DbContext` in parent child view, to manage the database.

How do I get all `DbContext` classes and all `DbSet` under each `DbContext`, in  LinQ query or in a C# function?

By using the following code, I got the list of DbSets under a `DbContext`, but in my case, there may be new `DbContext` too.

```
var metadata = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;

var tables = metadata.GetItemCollection(DataSpace.SSpace)
                     .GetItems<EntityContainer>()
                     .Single()
                     .BaseEntitySets
                     .OfType<EntitySet>()
                     .Where(s => !s.MetadataProperties.Contains("Type")
                                 || s.MetadataProperties["Type"].ToString() == "Tables");

foreach (var table in tables)
{
    var tableName = table.MetadataProperties.Contains("Table")
                    && table.MetadataProperties["Table"].Value != null
                    ? table.MetadataProperties["Table"].Value.ToString()
                    : table.Name;

    var tableSchema = table.MetadataProperties["Schema"].Value.ToString();

    Console.WriteLine(tableSchema + "." + tableName);
}
```

So I am looking for a dynamic list which should include the new DbContexts too.

How do I get all DbContext classes and all DbSet under each DbContex, in  LinQ query or in a c# function.

Comment: A single project with 50+ dbs?

Comment: No, even worse: there is only one database ("the database"), and multiple different DbContext classes that represent this one and only database. A future problem generator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like:

```
public Dictionary<Type, List<object>> FindDbContextsInAssemblies()
{
   var dbContexts = new Dictionary<Type, List<object>>();

   var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

   foreach(var assembly in assemblies)
   {
      foreach(var type in assembly.GetTypes())
      {
         if(type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(DbContext)))
         {
            // Instantiate DbContext:
            var context = type.GetConstructor(Array.Empty<Type>()).Invoke(Array.Empty<object>());

            // Find method to get entities:
            var model = type.GetProperty("Model");
            var searchMethod = model.PropertyType.GetMethod("GetEntityTypes");

            // Get registered entities:
            var entities = searchMethod.Invoke(model.GetValue(context, null), null) as List<object>;

            dbContexts[type] = entities;
         }
      }
   }

   return dbContexts;
}
```

Have not tested this. Idea is to comb through the assemblies, find the relevant classes and dynamically invoke [GetEntityTypes()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.imodel.getentitytypes#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_IModel_GetEntityTypes) method.